# Trying to make a small dice game - only works for one player, want to implement multiple players

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm totally new to Python and programming in general, and just starting to learn how to crawl, basically.  I decided to learn programming by doing, and so I tried to develop a little dice game.

The main intention (i did not manage to succeed in making the code like i wanted it to) was to make a game with the following rules:

- The game is played by two or more players
- There is only one dice involved in the game
- Object of the game is to be the first to get at least 100 points
- A player is chosen by random to go first: The player can roll the dice as many times as s/he likes, and the points are accumulated.  However, if the dice returns 1, the player loses the accumulated points.  At any time, the player can choose to stop rolling the dice and secure the points.  By doing this, the player loses its turn, and the next player can start rolling.  Points that are secured, can never be lost.

When first trying to make this code, I wanted to make it with classes and functions, but I just couldn't make that work.  Also I couldn't figure out how to design the game for multiple players.  I tried working with lists and dictionaries, but I just kept pulling my hair.  So I just tried to make the game for 1 player, where the objective is to reach a 100 points in fewest rounds (a new round starts everytime you secure points).  Not very fun, but at least I got it to work (well, sort of).

I would highly appreciate any comments to my little program.  Please note it's my first code, and I know it is really badly written.  I want to hear how you guys think the code could be improved, and how I should go about in organizing the code for multiple players.  I'm interested in learning to program for mobile devices at a later stage, and want to eventually turn this little game into an app so I can play with friends (for fun and as a way to learn the how-to's).

Hope the indents are adjusted properly.

```
from random import choice # Importing the random element to create the dice

score = 0
rounds = 1
secured = 0
unsecured = 0
ask = "N/A"

while secured+unsecured < 100:  # Check if the total score is below 100

    a = int(choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])) # Choose a dice number
    if a == 1: # Check if the dice is one
        if ask == "s": # Check if the player secured the last score
        print ("Good thing you just secured your score, because you now rolled a 1.")
        print ("Because of this, you only lost your round, not any points! :)")
        if ask =="N/A": # Check if the player rolled a one on the first throw
        print ("************* Round 1 ***********")
        print ("Tough luck, you rolled a ONE on your first roll. You lost one round.")
            rounds +=1
        if ask == "r": # Check if the player lost points that was unsecured
            print ("")
            print ("***** UH UH UH UH UH - YO ROLLED A ONE ******")
            print ("You lost the", unsecured,"points you didn't secure")
            unsecured = 0  # Player loses the unsecured points
            rounds +=1 # Increase round number
    else:
        unsecured = unsecured + a # If the dice returned something else than one, the player wins the points

    print ("")
    print ("")
    print ("************ Round ", rounds, "**************")
    print ("")
    if a > 1: # Only display the dice if the dice is higher than one (if it's one it has already been printed)
        print ("You rolled a ", a)
    print ("")

    print ("Unsecured points: ", unsecured)
    print ("Secured points:" , secured)
    print ("The sum of secured and unsecured pointsare:",secured+unsecured, "points")

    print ("")

    ask = input ("Roll the dice or secure? (r/s) ")

    if ask == "s":
        secured = secured+unsecured # If player chooses to secure the points, the points are added
        score = 0
        rounds +=1 # Increase round
        if unsecured == 0:  # Check if player was an idiot and chose to secure 0 points
            print ("You chose to secure zero points, not very clever! You wouldn't risk anything by rolling the dice, and you lost the round!")
        else:
            print ("You chose to secure your", unsecured, "points, and you have secured", secured, "points in total")
            print ("")
            unsecured = 0 # Reset unsecured points, since it is added to secure points
            input ("Press Enter to roll the dice:")
    else:
        if ask == "r":
            score = unsecured+a

else:
    print ("Congrats!  You made ",secured+unsecured, "points in", rounds , "rounds")
```

Comment: I think you wanted http://codereview.stackexchange.com, **if your code is tested and working correctly**. If not, please clarify the problem and cut the code down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In other words: what exactly does *"I got it to work (well, sort of)"* mean?

Comment: And in either case, you should review your code against [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), or provide a link to whatever alternative guide you're using.

Comment: This is really open ended question. There is no way how to answer this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Whether the code is working or not, is a matter of definition.  But yes, it runs (though not the way I want it to).  Perhaps I can try codereview, but I know the code is very badly written.  Don't want to piss people off.  I just recently starting coding, and I know there's tons of material to learn and digest.  I try to read about coding, but a lot of times I don't want to read, I want to write, experiment, try out things.  Oh, well.  Thanks againg.

Comment: Code-Review requires code to be running the way you want it to, so as of now this would be off-topic. If you get it to run the way you want it to run, then we'd be glad to review it ;)

Comment: And if you *can't* get it to run the way you want it to, edit the question to follow my guidance above.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  Then I will not post it to Code-Review, at least not yet.  I'm trying to figure out how my program can handle multiple players.  Still haven't given up in trying to find out how, though.  If anyone has any ideas on how I go about implementing this, it would help a lot.

Comment: A quick answer to get you started. first identify which variables must be kept alive for each player when there is a player change.  At first this is only ``secured``.  So turn it into a list, like: ``secured = [0, 0]``.  Add another ``current_player`` variable, 0 or 1, and access ``secured[current_player]`` instead of just ``secured``.

Comment: Thanks, Armin Rigo.  I knew that there would be an obvious answer to this, I just couldn't wrap my head around it.  Your answer was most helpful!